An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the do-release-upgrade from 23.10 to 24.04.1
I'm trying to upgrade my Ubuntu Studio from 23.10 to 24.04.1 but I get this error message:
Unable to determine which system updates are available
An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the system update.
It is suggested to have a look at »/var/log/dist-upgrade« main.log and apt.log which will be attached later.
I could not find anything for missing packages. There are some where they "failed to find a replacement" but have a look yourself:
I couln't fit the whole main.log in so here are some errors I found:
2024-09-28 13:17:48,236 DEBUG Searching for replacement for libiw30
       2024-09-28 13:17:48,237 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libiw30
       2024-09-28 13:17:57,121 DEBUG Searching for replacement for libpython3.11-minimal
       2024-09-28 13:17:57,121 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libpython3.11-minimal

And in apt.log I found this and also other errors:
Broken coreutils:amd64 Beschädigt on usrmerge:amd64 < 35ubuntu1 @ii mK > (< 39)
  Considering usrmerge:amd64 -3 as a solution to coreutils:amd64 5110
  Added usrmerge:amd64 to the remove list
  MarkDelete usrmerge:amd64 < 35ubuntu1 @ii mK > FU=0
  Fixing coreutils:amd64 via remove of usrmerge:amd64
Investigating (0) python3:amd64 < 3.11.4-5 -> 3.12.3-0ubuntu2 @ii umU Ib >
Broken python3:amd64 Kollidiert mit on python3-distutils:amd64 < 3.11.5-1 @ii mK Ib >
  Considering python3-distutils:amd64 -2 as a solution to python3:amd64 932
  Added python3-distutils:amd64 to the remove list
  MarkDelete python3-distutils:amd64 < 3.11.5-1 @ii mK Ib > FU=0
  Fixing python3:amd64 via remove of python3-distutils:amd64
Investigating (0) libsvtav1enc1d1:amd64 < none -> 1.7.0+dfsg-2build1 @un uN Ib >
Broken libsvtav1enc1d1:amd64 Beschädigt on libsvtav1enc1:amd64 < 1.6.0+dfsg-1 @ii mK > (< 1.6.0+dfsg-2~)
  Considering libsvtav1enc1:amd64 -3 as a solution to libsvtav1enc1d1:amd64 31
  Added libsvtav1enc1:amd64 to the remove list
Broken libsvtav1enc1d1:amd64 Beschädigt on libsvtav1enc1:i386 < 1.6.0+dfsg-1 @ii mK > (< 1.6.0+dfsg-2~)
  Considering libsvtav1enc1:i386 -4 as a solution to libsvtav1enc1d1:amd64 31
  Added libsvtav1enc1:i386 to the remove list
  MarkDelete libsvtav1enc1:amd64 < 1.6.0+dfsg-1 @ii mK > FU=0
  Fixing libsvtav1enc1d1:amd64 via remove of libsvtav1enc1:amd64
  MarkDelete libsvtav1enc1:i386 < 1.6.0+dfsg-1 @ii mK > FU=0
  Fixing libsvtav1enc1d1:amd64 via remove of libsvtav1enc1:i386
Investigating (0) php-common:amd64 < 2:93ubuntu1 -> 2:93ubuntu2 @ii umU Ib >
Broken php-common:amd64 Beschädigt on php8.2-common:amd64 < 8.2.10-2ubuntu2.2 @ii mK >
  Considering php8.2-common:amd64 3 as a solution to php-common:amd64 18
  Added php8.2-common:amd64 to the remove list
  MarkDelete php8.2-common:amd64 < 8.2.10-2ubuntu2.2 @ii mK > FU=0
  Fixing php-common:amd64 via remove of php8.2-common:amd64
Investigating (0) libtss2-mu-4.0.1-0t64:amd64 < none -> 4.0.1-7.1ubuntu5.1 @un umN Ib >
Broken libtss2-mu-4.0.1-0t64:amd64 Kollidiert mit on libtss2-mu0:amd64 < 4.0.1-3ubuntu1.1 @ii mK >
  Considering libtss2-mu0:amd64 -3 as a solution to libtss2-mu-4.0.1-0t64:amd64 14
  Added libtss2-mu0:amd64 to the remove list
  MarkDelete libtss2-mu0:amd64 < 4.0.1-3ubuntu1.1 @ii mK > FU=0
  Fixing libtss2-mu-4.0.1-0t64:amd64 via remove of libtss2-mu0:amd64
Investigating (0) libgeos-c1t64:amd64 < none -> 3.12.1-3build1 @un umN Ib >
Broken libgeos-c1t64:amd64 Hängt ab von on libgeos3.12.1t64:amd64 < none | 3.12.1-3build1 @un umH > (>= 3.12.1)
  Considering libgeos3.12.1t64:amd64 0 as a solution to libgeos-c1t64:amd64 3
  MarkKeep libgeos-c1t64:amd64 < none -> 3.12.1-3build1 @un umN Ib > FU=0
  Holding Back libgeos-c1t64:amd64 rather than change libgeos3.12.1t64:amd64
Investigating (0) libgdal34t64:amd64 < none -> 3.8.4+dfsg-3ubuntu3 @un umN Ib >
Broken libgdal34t64:amd64 Hängt ab von on libgeos-c1t64:amd64 < none | 3.12.1-3build1 @un umH > (>= 3.11.0)
  Considering libgeos-c1t64:amd64 3 as a solution to libgdal34t64:amd64 2
  MarkKeep libgdal34t64:amd64 < none -> 3.8.4+dfsg-3ubuntu3 @un umN Ib > FU=0
  Holding Back libgdal34t64:amd64 rather than change libgeos-c1t64:amd64
Investigating (0) libportsmf0t64:amd64 < none -> 0.1~svn20101010-7build1 @un uN Ib >
Broken libportsmf0t64:amd64 Beschädigt on libportsmf0v5:amd64 < 0.1~svn20101010-6ubuntu1 @ii mK Ib > (< 0.1~svn20101010-7build1)
  Considering libportsmf0v5:amd64 -3 as a solution to libportsmf0t64:amd64 2
  Added libportsmf0v5:amd64 to the remove list
  MarkDelete libportsmf0v5:amd64 < 0.1~svn20101010-6ubuntu1 @ii mK Ib > FU=0
  Fixing libportsmf0t64:amd64 via remove of libportsmf0v5:amd64
Investigating (0) libopencv-imgcodecs406t64:amd64 < none -> 4.6.0+dfsg-13.1ubuntu1 @un umN Ib >
Broken libopencv-imgcodecs406t64:amd64 Hängt ab von on libgdal34t64:amd64 < none | 3.8.4+dfsg-3ubuntu3 @un umH > (>= 2.0.1)
  Considering libgdal34t64:amd64 2 as a solution to libopencv-imgcodecs406t64:amd64 2
  MarkKeep libopencv-imgcodecs406t64:amd64 < none -> 4.6.0+dfsg-13.1ubuntu1 @un umN Ib > FU=0
  Holding Back libopencv-imgcodecs406t64:amd64 rather than change libgdal34t64:amd64
Investigating (0) libiw30t64:amd64 < none -> 30~pre9-16.1ubuntu2 @un uN Ib >
Broken libiw30t64:amd64 Kollidiert mit on libiw30:amd64 < 30~pre9-13.1ubuntu4 @ii mK > (< 30~pre9-16.1ubuntu2)
  Considering libiw30:amd64 -3 as a solution to libiw30t64:amd64 2
  Added libiw30:amd64 to the remove list
  MarkDelete libiw30:amd64 < 30~pre9-13.1ubuntu4 @ii mK > FU=0
  Fixing libiw30t64:amd64 via remove of libiw30:amd64
Investigating (0) libopencv-videoio406t64:amd64 < none -> 4.6.0+dfsg-13.1ubuntu1 @un umN Ib >
Broken libopencv-videoio406t64:amd64 Hängt ab von on libopencv-imgcodecs406t64:amd64 < none | 4.6.0+dfsg-13.1ubuntu1 @un umH > (>= 4.6.0+dfsg)
  Considering libopencv-imgcodecs406t64:amd64 2 as a solution to libopencv-videoio406t64:amd64 2
  MarkKeep libopencv-videoio406t64:amd64 < none -> 4.6.0+dfsg-13.1ubuntu1 @un umN Ib > FU=0
  Holding Back libopencv-videoio406t64:amd64 rather than change libopencv-imgcodecs406t64:amd64
Investigating (0) libsnmp40t64:i386 < none -> 5.9.4+dfsg-1.1ubuntu3 @un umN Ib >
Broken libsnmp40t64:i386 Hängt ab von on libperl5.38t64:i386 < none | 5.38.2-3.2build2 @un umH > (>= 5.38.2)
  Considering libperl5.38t64:i386 0 as a solution to libsnmp40t64:i386 1
  MarkKeep libsnmp40t64:i386 < none -> 5.9.4+dfsg-1.1ubuntu3 @un umN Ib > FU=0
  Holding Back libsnmp40t64:i386 rather than change libperl5.38t64:i386
Investigating (0) librttopo1:amd64 < 1.1.0-3 -> 1.1.0-3build2 @ii umU Ib >
Broken librttopo1:amd64 Hängt ab von on libgeos-c1t64:amd64 < none | 3.12.1-3build1 @un umH > (>= 3.5.0)
  Considering libgeos-c1t64:amd64 3 as a solution to librttopo1:amd64 1
  MarkKeep librttopo1:amd64 < 1.1.0-3 -> 1.1.0-3build2 @ii umU Ib > FU=0
  Removing librttopo1:amd64 rather than change libgeos-c1t64:amd64
  MarkDelete librttopo1:amd64 < 1.1.0-3 | 1.1.0-3build2 @ii umH Ib > FU=0
Investigating (0) libsane1:i386 < 1.2.1-5 -> 1.2.1-7build4 @ii umU NPb Ib >
Broken libsane1:i386 Hängt ab von on libsnmp40t64:i386 < none | 5.9.4+dfsg-1.1ubuntu3 @un umH > (>= 5.9.4+dfsg)
  Considering libsnmp40t64:i386 1 as a solution to libsane1:i386 1
  MarkKeep libsane1:i386 < 1.2.1-5 -> 1.2.1-7build4 @ii umU NPb Ib > FU=0
  Removing libsane1:i386 rather than change libsnmp40t64:i386
  MarkDelete libsane1:i386 < 1.2.1-5 | 1.2.1-7build4 @ii umH NPb Ib > FU=0
Investigating (0) libpoppler-glib8t64:i386 < none -> 24.02.0-1ubuntu9.1 @un umN Ib >
Broken libpoppler-glib8t64:i386 Hängt ab von on libpoppler134:i386 < none | 24.02.0-1ubuntu9.1 @un umH > (= 24.02.0-1ubuntu9.1)
  Considering libpoppler134:i386 0 as a solution to libpoppler-glib8t64:i386 1
  MarkKeep libpoppler-glib8t64:i386 < none -> 24.02.0-1ubuntu9.1 @un umN Ib > FU=0
  Holding Back libpoppler-glib8t64:i386 rather than change libpoppler134:i386
Investigating (0) libspatialite8t64:amd64 < none -> 5.1.0-3build1 @un umN Ib >
Broken libspatialite8t64:amd64 Hängt ab von on libgeos-c1t64:amd64 < none | 3.12.1-3build1 @un umH > (>= 3.11.0)
  Considering libgeos-c1t64:amd64 3 as a solution to libspatialite8t64:amd64 0
  MarkKeep libspatialite8t64:amd64 < none -> 5.1.0-3build1 @un umN Ib > FU=0
  Holding Back libspatialite8t64:amd64 rather than change libgeos-c1t64:amd64
Investigating (0) libopencv-highgui406t64:amd64 < none -> 4.6.0+dfsg-13.1ubuntu1 @un umN Ib >
Broken libopencv-highgui406t64:amd64 Hängt ab von on libopencv-imgcodecs406t64:amd64 < none | 4.6.0+dfsg-13.1ubuntu1 @un umH > (>= 4.6.0+dfsg)
  Considering libopencv-imgcodecs406t64:amd64 2 as a solution to libopencv-highgui406t64:amd64 0
  MarkKeep libopencv-highgui406t64:amd64 < none -> 4.6.0+dfsg-13.1ubuntu1 @un umN Ib > FU=0
  Holding Back libopencv-highgui406t64:amd64 rather than change libopencv-imgcodecs406t64:amd64
Investigating (0) php8.2-opcache:amd64 < 8.2.10-2ubuntu2.2 @ii mK Ib >
Broken php8.2-opcache:amd64 Hängt ab von on php8.2-common:amd64 < 8.2.10-2ubuntu2.2 @ii mR > (= 8.2.10-2ubuntu2.2)
  Considering php8.2-common:amd64 3 as a solution to php8.2-opcache:amd64 0
  Removing php8.2-opcache:amd64 rather than change php8.2-common:amd64
  MarkDelete php8.2-opcache:amd64 < 8.2.10-2ubuntu2.2 @ii mK Ib > FU=0
Investigating (0) php8.2-cli:amd64 < 8.2.10-2ubuntu2.2 @ii mK Ib >
Broken php8.2-cli:amd64 Hängt ab von on php8.2-common:amd64 < 8.2.10-2ubuntu2.2 @ii mR > (= 8.2.10-2ubuntu2.2)
  Considering php8.2-common:amd64 3 as a solution to php8.2-cli:amd64 -1
  Removing php8.2-cli:amd64 rather than change php8.2-common:amd64
  MarkDelete php8.2-cli:amd64 < 8.2.10-2ubuntu2.2 @ii mK Ib > FU=0
Investigating (0) php8.2-readline:amd64 < 8.2.10-2ubuntu2.2 @ii mK Ib >
Broken php8.2-readline:amd64 Hängt ab von on php8.2-common:amd64 < 8.2.10-2ubuntu2.2 @ii mR > (= 8.2.10-2ubuntu2.2)
  Considering php8.2-common:amd64 3 as a solution to php8.2-readline:amd64 -1
  Removing php8.2-readline:amd64 rather than change php8.2-common:amd64
  MarkDelete php8.2-readline:amd64 < 8.2.10-2ubuntu2.2 @ii mK Ib > FU=0
Investigating (0) libapache2-mod-php8.2:amd64 < 8.2.10-2ubuntu2.2 @ii mK Ib >
Broken libapache2-mod-php8.2:amd64 Hängt ab von on php8.2-cli:amd64 < 8.2.10-2ubuntu2.2 @ii mR >
  Considering php8.2-cli:amd64 -1 as a solution to libapache2-mod-php8.2:amd64 -1
  Removing libapache2-mod-php8.2:amd64 rather than change php8.2-cli:amd64
  MarkDelete libapache2-mod-php8.2:amd64 < 8.2.10-2ubuntu2.2 @ii mK Ib > FU=0
Investigating (0) php8.2-mysql:amd64 < 8.2.10-2ubuntu2.2 @ii mK Ib >
Broken php8.2-mysql:amd64 Hängt ab von on php8.2-common:amd64 < 8.2.10-2ubuntu2.2 @ii mR > (= 8.2.10-2ubuntu2.2)
  Considering php8.2-common:amd64 3 as a solution to php8.2-mysql:amd64 -2
  Removing php8.2-mysql:amd64 rather than change php8.2-common:amd64
  MarkDelete php8.2-mysql:amd64 < 8.2.10-2ubuntu2.2 @ii mK Ib > FU=0
Investigating (0) php8.2:amd64 < 8.2.10-2ubuntu2.2 @ii mK Ib >
Broken php8.2:amd64 Hängt ab von on libapache2-mod-php8.2:amd64 < 8.2.10-2ubuntu2.2 @ii mR >
  Considering libapache2-mod-php8.2:amd64 -1 as a solution to php8.2:amd64 -2
Broken php8.2:amd64 Hängt ab von on php8.2-fpm:amd64 < none @un mH >
Broken php8.2:amd64 Hängt ab von on php8.2-cgi:amd64 < none @un mH >
  Or group remove for php8.2:amd64
  MarkDelete php8.2:amd64 < 8.2.10-2ubuntu2.2 @ii mK Ib > FU=0
Broken php8.2:amd64 Hängt ab von on php8.2-common:amd64 < 8.2.10-2ubuntu2.2 @ii mR >
  Considering php8.2-common:amd64 3 as a solution to php8.2:amd64 -2
  MarkKeep php8.2:amd64 < 8.2.10-2ubuntu2.2 @ii mR > FU=0
  Removing php8.2:amd64 rather than change php8.2-common:amd64
  MarkDelete php8.2:amd64 < 8.2.10-2ubuntu2.2 @ii mK Ib > FU=0
Investigating (0) libgdal33:amd64 < 3.7.1+dfsg-1build1 @ii mK Ib >
Broken libgdal33:amd64 Hängt ab von on libgeos-c1v5:amd64 < 3.12.0-1 @ii pmR > (>= 3.11.0~beta1)
  Considering libgeos-c1v5:amd64 0 as a solution to libgdal33:amd64 -2
  Removing libgdal33:amd64 rather than change libgeos-c1v5:amd64
  MarkDelete libgdal33:amd64 < 3.7.1+dfsg-1build1 @ii mK Ib > FU=0
Investigating (0) wine-devel-i386:i386 < 9.9~jammy-1 @ii mK Ib >
Broken wine-devel-i386:i386 Hängt ab von on libsane1:i386 < 1.2.1-5 | 1.2.1-7build4 @ii umR NPb > (>= 1.0.27)
  Considering libsane1:i386 1 as a solution to wine-devel-i386:i386 -2
  Removing wine-devel-i386:i386 rather than change libsane1:i386
  MarkDelete wine-devel-i386:i386 < 9.9~jammy-1 @ii mK Ib > FU=0
Investigating (0) libavif15:amd64 < 0.11.1-3ubuntu1 @ii mK Ib >
Broken libavif15:amd64 Hängt ab von on libsvtav1enc1:amd64 < 1.6.0+dfsg-1 @ii mR > (>= 1.6.0+dfsg)
  Considering libsvtav1enc1:amd64 -3 as a solution to libavif15:amd64 -2
  Added libsvtav1enc1:amd64 to the remove list
  MarkKeep libsvtav1enc1:amd64 < 1.6.0+dfsg-1 @ii mR > FU=0
  Fixing libavif15:amd64 via keep of libsvtav1enc1:amd64
Investigating (0) python3.11-venv:amd64 < 3.11.6-3ubuntu0.1 @ii mK Ib >
Broken python3.11-venv:amd64 Hängt ab von on python3.11-distutils:amd64 < none @un mH >
  Considering python3-distutils:amd64 -2 as a solution to python3.11-venv:amd64 -2
  Removing python3.11-venv:amd64 rather than change python3.11-distutils:amd64
  MarkDelete python3.11-venv:amd64 < 3.11.6-3ubuntu0.1 @ii mK Ib > FU=0
Investigating (1) libsvtav1enc1d1:amd64 < none -> 1.7.0+dfsg-2build1 @un uN Ib >
Broken libsvtav1enc1d1:amd64 Beschädigt on libsvtav1enc1:amd64 < 1.6.0+dfsg-1 @ii mK > (< 1.6.0+dfsg-2~)
  Considering libsvtav1enc1:amd64 -3 as a solution to libsvtav1enc1d1:amd64 31
  Added libsvtav1enc1:amd64 to the remove list
  MarkDelete libsvtav1enc1:amd64 < 1.6.0+dfsg-1 @ii mK > FU=0
  Fixing libsvtav1enc1d1:amd64 via remove of libsvtav1enc1:amd64
Investigating (1) libopencv-contrib406t64:amd64 < none -> 4.6.0+dfsg-13.1ubuntu1 @un umN Ib >
Broken libopencv-contrib406t64:amd64 Hängt ab von on libopencv-highgui406t64:amd64 < none | 4.6.0+dfsg-13.1ubuntu1 @un umH > (>= 4.6.0+dfsg)
  Considering libopencv-highgui406t64:amd64 0 as a solution to libopencv-contrib406t64:amd64 3
  MarkKeep libopencv-contrib406t64:amd64 < none -> 4.6.0+dfsg-13.1ubuntu1 @un umN Ib > FU=0
  Holding Back libopencv-contrib406t64:amd64 rather than change libopencv-highgui406t64:amd64
Investigating (1) libopenscenegraph161:amd64 < 3.6.5+dfsg1-8build3 -> 3.6.5+dfsg1-8build10 @ii umU Ib >
Broken libopenscenegraph161:amd64 Hängt ab von on libgdal34:amd64 < none @un H > (>= 3.0.0)
  Considering libgdal34t64:amd64 2 as a solution to libopenscenegraph161:amd64 2
  MarkKeep libopenscenegraph161:amd64 < 3.6.5+dfsg1-8build3 -> 3.6.5+dfsg1-8build10 @ii umU Ib > FU=0
  Removing libopenscenegraph161:amd64 rather than change libgdal34:amd64
  MarkDelete libopenscenegraph161:amd64 < 3.6.5+dfsg1-8build3 | 3.6.5+dfsg1-8build10 @ii umH Ib > FU=0
Investigating (1) libgmic1:amd64 < 2.9.4-4build4 -> 2.9.4-4build11 @ii umU Ib >
Broken libgmic1:amd64 Hängt ab von on libopencv-videoio406t64:amd64 < none | 4.6.0+dfsg-13.1ubuntu1 @un umH > (>= 4.6.0+dfsg)
  Considering libopencv-videoio406t64:amd64 2 as a solution to libgmic1:amd64 2
  MarkKeep libgmic1:amd64 < 2.9.4-4build4 -> 2.9.4-4build11 @ii umU Ib > FU=0
  Removing libgmic1:amd64 rather than change libopencv-videoio406t64:amd64
  MarkDelete libgmic1:amd64 < 2.9.4-4build4 | 2.9.4-4build11 @ii umH Ib > FU=0
Investigating (1) scribus:amd64 < 1.5.8+dfsg-4build4 -> 1.6.1-0ubuntu7 @ii umU Ib >
Broken scribus:amd64 Hängt ab von on libopenscenegraph161:amd64 < 3.6.5+dfsg1-8build3 | 3.6.5+dfsg1-8build10 @ii umR > (>= 3.6.5+dfsg1)
  Considering libopenscenegraph161:amd64 2 as a solution to scribus:amd64 1
  MarkKeep scribus:amd64 < 1.5.8+dfsg-4build4 -> 1.6.1-0ubuntu7 @ii umU Ib > FU=0
  Removing scribus:amd64 rather than change libopenscenegraph161:amd64
  MarkDelete scribus:amd64 < 1.5.8+dfsg-4build4 | 1.6.1-0ubuntu7 @ii umH Ib > FU=0
Investigating (1) gmic:amd64 < 2.9.4-4build4 -> 2.9.4-4build11 @ii umU Ib >
Broken gmic:amd64 Hängt ab von on libgmic1:amd64 < 2.9.4-4build4 | 2.9.4-4build11 @ii umR > (= 2.9.4-4build11)
  Considering libgmic1:amd64 2 as a solution to gmic:amd64 0
  MarkKeep gmic:amd64 < 2.9.4-4build4 -> 2.9.4-4build11 @ii umU Ib > FU=0
  Removing gmic:amd64 rather than change libgmic1:amd64
  MarkDelete gmic:amd64 < 2.9.4-4build4 | 2.9.4-4build11 @ii umH Ib > FU=0
Investigating (1) gimp-gmic:amd64 < 2.9.4-4build4 -> 2.9.4-4build11 @ii umU Ib >
Broken gimp-gmic:amd64 Hängt ab von on libgmic1:amd64 < 2.9.4-4build4 | 2.9.4-4build11 @ii umR > (= 2.9.4-4build11)
  Considering libgmic1:amd64 2 as a solution to gimp-gmic:amd64 0
  MarkKeep gimp-gmic:amd64 < 2.9.4-4build4 -> 2.9.4-4build11 @ii umU Ib > FU=0
  Removing gimp-gmic:amd64 rather than change libgmic1:amd64
  MarkDelete gimp-gmic:amd64 < 2.9.4-4build4 | 2.9.4-4build11 @ii umH Ib > FU=0
Investigating (1) wine-devel:amd64 < 9.9~jammy-1 @ii mK Ib >
Broken wine-devel:amd64 Hängt ab von on wine-devel-i386:amd64 < none @un mH > (= 9.9~jammy-1)
  Considering wine-devel-i386:i386 -2 as a solution to wine-devel:amd64 -1
  Added wine-devel-i386:i386 to the remove list
  MarkKeep wine-devel-i386:i386 < 9.9~jammy-1 @ii mR > FU=0
  Fixing wine-devel:amd64 via keep of wine-devel-i386:i386
Investigating (1) wine-devel-i386:i386 < 9.9~jammy-1 @ii mK Ib >
Broken wine-devel-i386:i386 Hängt ab von on libsane1:i386 < 1.2.1-5 | 1.2.1-7build4 @ii umR NPb > (>= 1.0.27)
  Considering libsane1:i386 1 as a solution to wine-devel-i386:i386 -2
  Removing wine-devel-i386:i386 rather than change libsane1:i386
  MarkDelete wine-devel-i386:i386 < 9.9~jammy-1 @ii mK Ib > FU=0
Investigating (1) libavif15:amd64 < 0.11.1-3ubuntu1 @ii mK Ib >
Broken libavif15:amd64 Hängt ab von on libsvtav1enc1:amd64 < 1.6.0+dfsg-1 @ii mR > (>= 1.6.0+dfsg)
  Considering libsvtav1enc1:amd64 -3 as a solution to libavif15:amd64 -2
  Added libsvtav1enc1:amd64 to the remove list
  MarkKeep libsvtav1enc1:amd64 < 1.6.0+dfsg-1 @ii mR > FU=0
  Fixing libavif15:amd64 via keep of libsvtav1enc1:amd64
Investigating (2) libsvtav1enc1d1:amd64 < none -> 1.7.0+dfsg-2build1 @un uN Ib >
Broken libsvtav1enc1d1:amd64 Beschädigt on libsvtav1enc1:amd64 < 1.6.0+dfsg-1 @ii mK > (< 1.6.0+dfsg-2~)
  Considering libsvtav1enc1:amd64 -3 as a solution to libsvtav1enc1d1:amd64 31
  Added libsvtav1enc1:amd64 to the remove list
  MarkDelete libsvtav1enc1:amd64 < 1.6.0+dfsg-1 @ii mK > FU=0
  Fixing libsvtav1enc1d1:amd64 via remove of libsvtav1enc1:amd64
Investigating (2) libmlt7:amd64 < 7.18.0-1 -> 7.22.0-1build6 @ii umU Ib >
Broken libmlt7:amd64 Hängt ab von on libopencv-contrib406t64:amd64 < none | 4.6.0+dfsg-13.1ubuntu1 @un umH > (>= 4.6.0+dfsg)
  Considering libopencv-contrib406t64:amd64 3 as a solution to libmlt7:amd64 8
  MarkKeep libmlt7:amd64 < 7.18.0-1 -> 7.22.0-1build6 @ii umU Ib > FU=0
  Removing libmlt7:amd64 rather than change libopencv-contrib406t64:amd64
  MarkDelete libmlt7:amd64 < 7.18.0-1 | 7.22.0-1build6 @ii umH Ib > FU=0
Investigating (2) libmlt++7:amd64 < 7.18.0-1 -> 7.22.0-1build6 @ii umU Ib >
Broken libmlt++7:amd64 Hängt ab von on libmlt7:amd64 < 7.18.0-1 | 7.22.0-1build6 @ii umR > (>= 7.22.0)
  Considering libmlt7:amd64 8 as a solution to libmlt++7:amd64 7
  MarkKeep libmlt++7:amd64 < 7.18.0-1 -> 7.22.0-1build6 @ii umU Ib > FU=0
  Removing libmlt++7:amd64 rather than change libmlt7:amd64
  MarkDelete libmlt++7:amd64 < 7.18.0-1 | 7.22.0-1build6 @ii umH Ib > FU=0
Investigating (2) kdenlive:amd64 < 4:23.08.1-0ubuntu1 -> 4:23.08.5-0ubuntu4 @ii umU Ib >
Broken kdenlive:amd64 Hängt ab von on libmlt++7:amd64 < 7.18.0-1 | 7.22.0-1build6 @ii umR > (>= 7.22.0)
  Considering libmlt++7:amd64 8 as a solution to kdenlive:amd64 3
  MarkKeep kdenlive:amd64 < 4:23.08.1-0ubuntu1 -> 4:23.08.5-0ubuntu4 @ii umU Ib > FU=0
  Removing kdenlive:amd64 rather than change libmlt++7:amd64
  MarkDelete kdenlive:amd64 < 4:23.08.1-0ubuntu1 | 4:23.08.5-0ubuntu4 @ii umH Ib > FU=0
Investigating (2) melt:amd64 < 7.18.0-1 -> 7.22.0-1build6 @ii umU Ib >
Broken melt:amd64 Hängt ab von on libmlt7:amd64 < 7.18.0-1 | 7.22.0-1build6 @ii umR > (>= 7.22.0)
  Considering libmlt7:amd64 8 as a solution to melt:amd64 3
  MarkKeep melt:amd64 < 7.18.0-1 -> 7.22.0-1build6 @ii umU Ib > FU=0
  Removing melt:amd64 rather than change libmlt7:amd64
  MarkDelete melt:amd64 < 7.18.0-1 | 7.22.0-1build6 @ii umH Ib > FU=0
Investigating (2) wine-devel:amd64 < 9.9~jammy-1 @ii mK Ib >
Broken wine-devel:amd64 Hängt ab von on wine-devel-i386:amd64 < none @un mH > (= 9.9~jammy-1)
  Considering wine-devel-i386:i386 -2 as a solution to wine-devel:amd64 -1
  Added wine-devel-i386:i386 to the remove list
  MarkKeep wine-devel-i386:i386 < 9.9~jammy-1 @ii mR > FU=0
  Fixing wine-devel:amd64 via keep of wine-devel-i386:i386
Investigating (2) wine-devel-i386:i386 < 9.9~jammy-1 @ii mK Ib >
Broken wine-devel-i386:i386 Hängt ab von on libsane1:i386 < 1.2.1-5 | 1.2.1-7build4 @ii umR NPb > (>= 1.0.27)
  Considering libsane1:i386 1 as a solution to wine-devel-i386:i386 -1
  Removing wine-devel-i386:i386 rather than change libsane1:i386
  MarkDelete wine-devel-i386:i386 < 9.9~jammy-1 @ii mK Ib > FU=0
Investigating (2) libavif15:amd64 < 0.11.1-3ubuntu1 @ii mK Ib >
Broken libavif15:amd64 Hängt ab von on libsvtav1enc1:amd64 < 1.6.0+dfsg-1 @ii mR > (>= 1.6.0+dfsg)
  Considering libsvtav1enc1:amd64 31 as a solution to libavif15:amd64 -2
  Removing libavif15:amd64 rather than change libsvtav1enc1:amd64
  MarkDelete libavif15:amd64 < 0.11.1-3ubuntu1 @ii mK Ib > FU=0
Investigating (3) wine-devel:amd64 < 9.9~jammy-1 @ii mK Ib >
Broken wine-devel:amd64 Hängt ab von on wine-devel-i386:amd64 < none @un mH > (= 9.9~jammy-1)
  Considering wine-devel-i386:i386 1 as a solution to wine-devel:amd64 -1
  Removing wine-devel:amd64 rather than change wine-devel-i386:amd64
  MarkDelete wine-devel:amd64 < 9.9~jammy-1 @ii mK Ib > FU=0
Investigating (3) wine-devel-dev:amd64 < 9.9~jammy-1 @ii mK Ib >
Broken wine-devel-dev:amd64 Hängt ab von on wine-devel-i386:amd64 < none @un mH > (= 9.9~jammy-1)
  Considering wine-devel-i386:i386 1 as a solution to wine-devel-dev:amd64 -2
  Removing wine-devel-dev:amd64 rather than change wine-devel-i386:amd64
  MarkDelete wine-devel-dev:amd64 < 9.9~jammy-1 @ii mK Ib > FU=0
Investigating (4) winehq-devel:amd64 < 9.9~jammy-1 @ii mK Ib >
Broken winehq-devel:amd64 Hängt ab von on wine-devel:amd64 < 9.9~jammy-1 @ii mR > (= 9.9~jammy-1)
  Considering wine-devel:amd64 1 as a solution to winehq-devel:amd64 0
  Removing winehq-devel:amd64 rather than change wine-devel:amd64
  MarkDelete winehq-devel:amd64 < 9.9~jammy-1 @ii mK Ib > FU=0
Investigating (4) winetricks:amd64 < 20230212-2 -> 20240105-2 @ii umU Ib >
Broken winetricks:amd64 Hängt ab von on wine:amd64 < none | 9.0~repack-4build3 @un umH >
  Considering wine:amd64 1 as a solution to winetricks:amd64 0
  MarkKeep winetricks:amd64 < 20230212-2 -> 20240105-2 @ii umU Ib > FU=0
  Removing winetricks:amd64 rather than change wine:amd64
  MarkDelete winetricks:amd64 < 20230212-2 | 20240105-2 @ii umH Ib > FU=0
Investigating (5) carla-bridge-wine64:amd64 < 2.5.7-0ubuntu1 -> 2.5.8-0ubuntu5 @ii umU Ib >
Broken carla-bridge-wine64:amd64 Hängt ab von on wine-development:amd64 < none @un mH >
Broken carla-bridge-wine64:amd64 Hängt ab von on wine-staging:amd64 < none @un mH >
Broken carla-bridge-wine64:amd64 Hängt ab von on wine-stable:amd64 < none | 3.0.1ubuntu1 @un umH >
  Considering wine-stable:amd64 1 as a solution to carla-bridge-wine64:amd64 2
  MarkKeep carla-bridge-wine64:amd64 < 2.5.7-0ubuntu1 -> 2.5.8-0ubuntu5 @ii umU Ib > FU=0
  Try Installing wine-stable:amd64 < none | 3.0.1ubuntu1 @un umH > before changing carla-bridge-wine64:amd64
    MarkInstall wine-stable:amd64 < none -> 3.0.1ubuntu1 @un umN Ib > FU=0
    Installing winehq-devel:amd64 as Hängt ab von of wine-stable:amd64
        MarkKeep winehq-devel:amd64 < 9.9~jammy-1 @ii mR > FU=0
Investigating (5) winehq-devel:amd64 < 9.9~jammy-1 @ii mK Ib >
Broken winehq-devel:amd64 Hängt ab von on wine-devel:amd64 < 9.9~jammy-1 @ii mR > (= 9.9~jammy-1)
  Considering wine-devel:amd64 1 as a solution to winehq-devel:amd64 1
  Removing winehq-devel:amd64 rather than change wine-devel:amd64
  MarkDelete winehq-devel:amd64 < 9.9~jammy-1 @ii mK Ib > FU=0
 Try to Re-Instate (6) carla-bridge-wine64:amd64
Re-Instated carla-bridge-wine64:amd64 (1 vs 1)
Investigating (6) wine-stable:amd64 < none -> 3.0.1ubuntu1 @un umN Ib >
Broken wine-stable:amd64 Hängt ab von on wine:amd64 < none | 9.0~repack-4build3 @un umH >
  Considering wine:amd64 1 as a solution to wine-stable:amd64 1
  MarkKeep wine-stable:amd64 < none -> 3.0.1ubuntu1 @un umN Ib > FU=0
  Holding Back wine-stable:amd64 rather than change wine:amd64
Investigating (7) carla-bridge-wine64:amd64 < 2.5.7-0ubuntu1 -> 2.5.8-0ubuntu5 @ii umU Ib >
Broken carla-bridge-wine64:amd64 Hängt ab von on wine-development:amd64 < none @un mH >
Broken carla-bridge-wine64:amd64 Hängt ab von on wine-staging:amd64 < none @un mH >
Broken carla-bridge-wine64:amd64 Hängt ab von on wine-stable:amd64 < none | 3.0.1ubuntu1 @un umH >
  Considering wine-stable:amd64 1 as a solution to carla-bridge-wine64:amd64 2
  MarkKeep carla-bridge-wine64:amd64 < 2.5.7-0ubuntu1 -> 2.5.8-0ubuntu5 @ii umU Ib > FU=0
  Try Installing wine-stable:amd64 < none | 3.0.1ubuntu1 @un umH > before changing carla-bridge-wine64:amd64
    MarkInstall wine-stable:amd64 < none -> 3.0.1ubuntu1 @un umN Ib > FU=0
    Installing winehq-devel:amd64 as Hängt ab von of wine-stable:amd64
        MarkKeep winehq-devel:amd64 < 9.9~jammy-1 @ii mR > FU=0
Investigating (7) winehq-devel:amd64 < 9.9~jammy-1 @ii mK Ib >
Broken winehq-devel:amd64 Hängt ab von on wine-devel:amd64 < 9.9~jammy-1 @ii mR > (= 9.9~jammy-1)
  Considering wine-devel:amd64 1 as a solution to winehq-devel:amd64 1
  Removing winehq-devel:amd64 rather than change wine-devel:amd64
  MarkDelete winehq-devel:amd64 < 9.9~jammy-1 @ii mK Ib > FU=0
Investigating (8) wine-stable:amd64 < none -> 3.0.1ubuntu1 @un umN Ib >
Broken wine-stable:amd64 Hängt ab von on wine:amd64 < none | 9.0~repack-4build3 @un umH >
  Considering wine:amd64 1 as a solution to wine-stable:amd64 1
  MarkKeep wine-stable:amd64 < none -> 3.0.1ubuntu1 @un umN Ib > FU=0
  Holding Back wine-stable:amd64 rather than change wine:amd64
Investigating (9) carla-bridge-wine64:amd64 < 2.5.7-0ubuntu1 | 2.5.8-0ubuntu5 @ii umH Ib >
Broken carla-bridge-wine64:amd64 Hängt ab von on wine-development:amd64 < none @un mH >
Broken carla-bridge-wine64:amd64 Hängt ab von on wine-staging:amd64 < none @un mH >
Broken carla-bridge-wine64:amd64 Hängt ab von on wine-stable:amd64 < none | 3.0.1ubuntu1 @un umH >
  Considering wine-stable:amd64 1 as a solution to carla-bridge-wine64:amd64 2
  Try Installing wine-stable:amd64 < none | 3.0.1ubuntu1 @un umH > before changing carla-bridge-wine64:amd64
    MarkInstall wine-stable:amd64 < none -> 3.0.1ubuntu1 @un umN Ib > FU=0
    Installing winehq-devel:amd64 as Hängt ab von of wine-stable:amd64
        MarkKeep winehq-devel:amd64 < 9.9~jammy-1 @ii mR > FU=0
Investigating (9) winehq-devel:amd64 < 9.9~jammy-1 @ii mK Ib >
Broken winehq-devel:amd64 Hängt ab von on wine-devel:amd64 < 9.9~jammy-1 @ii mR > (= 9.9~jammy-1)

So as I couldn't find a hint what's the problem (seems something with the dependencies) It could be time for a fresh install?
Thanks for helping.

This question is similar to: How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

FYI:  Because mantic or 23.10 is EOL, and also that wasn't recent (thus online sources have already been dropped); we can't easily check details where we're using other releases (and I sure don't have any non-upgraded mantic/23.10 systems nearby). If you need help from others, I suggest you ask for help before or very soon after EOL when resources for your release are still available...   It looks like you're problems are 3rd party package caused to me; but again I don't have a 23.10 system to confirm & CLI checks are no longer available (mantic databases dropped)

Unfortunately, you have missed the support window for migration from Ubuntu 23.10 to 24.04.

The window for 23.10 to 24.04 ran from 2024-04 to 2024-07.
The window for 22.04 to 24.04 opened 2024-08, and remains open until 2027-04.

The only path to migration from 23.10 to 24.04 that we will provide support for is backing up your 23.10 data and new-installing 24.04.
There are other paths possible, and you are welcome to try them if you have the skills. But we won't answer questions about them nor provide any support for them anymore.
